# how to combine a WITH statement and an INSERT INTO in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I have an sql statement with a with clause and I want to write the results into a table with insert into. Any combination of with and insert into I tried gave me an error message. Minimal example of what I want to do:

```
create table temp as (quarter decimal(5));

insert into temp (
with bla as (select 2021 as year from dummy)
select 10*year + 1 as quarter from bla
)
```

Putting the with statement outside the insert into doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Oracle, you want the syntax:

```sql
insert into temp (quarter)
with bla (year) as (
  select 2021 as year from dual
)
select 10*year + 1 as quarter from bla;
```

And your `CREATE TABLE` statement should be:

```sql
create table temp (quarter decimal(5));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d0eca5bed669c4b4ad2f39387b5342a6)*