# Perform Insert Select from With data

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to insert the same set of data for each user in my database. This is a distributed database, where each target has its own instance of the db and a different number of users. I am doing something like the below:

```
with insertData (profileId, intData, stringData) as (
    select u.UserProfileID, 0, 'data1' from (select up.UserProfileID from userprofile up) u union
    select u.UserProfileID, 1, 'data2' from (select up.UserProfileID from userprofile up) u union
    select u.UserProfileID, 2, 'data3' from (select up.UserProfileID from userprofile up) u union
)
insert into targetTable (UserProfileID, IntData, StringData)
select profileId, intData, stringData
from insertData;
```

Inefficiencies aside, this does not work. I receive SQL Error [1064] [42000]. If I comment out the insert line, the select works perfectly, which seems to indicate that the `with` function doesn't work the same (or maybe at all?) with `insert..select`. Everything I've found only discusses `insert..select` or `with` as separate items, but I cannot find anything that combines the two. Am I doing something wrong here, or is it just not possible to combine `with` with `insert..select`?

Comment: A slight alteration to my google search finally found the answer I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385042/how-to-combine-a-with-statement-and-an-insert-into-in-sql.

Comment: "I receive SQL Error [1064] [42000]" the message of the error is much more helpful than its number

Comment: @HoneyBadger It's literally just "You have an error in your SQL syntax". Wholly unhelpful. It's so generic, I just assumed it was widely known.

Comment: well, I for one, don't work with mariadb enough to know the error codes (even the generic ones) by heart. So even the generic message could've helped me find the problem. Glad you found the solution anyway

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yeah, my bad for assuming. Thanks, anyway.